# Artefacts while installing ubuntu

Tags: installation, display

While installing ubuntu I have faced display problems, like on screenshot:

[image: https://www.dropbox.com/s/qz296ypayd9gufy/IMG_20130820_120254.jpg]

Thanks for any help!

Comment: what PC are you on? is it a desktop? a laptop? which brand/model? Do you have an nvidia video card?

Comment: It is desktop Core i5-3330 with integrated video adapter (Intel HD graphics)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Boot from CD or USB stick, before the OS starts (as soon as you see the small keyboard icon to the bottom) press any key.

You'll end up in a boot menu. Select your language if you are asked, then press F6 and select "nomodeset", press ESC and run the live cd by selecting "Try Ubuntu"

If it doesn't work try by adding the nomodeset option manually to the boot options string that will appear as soon as you press F6